# Change flyway-maven-plugin's default scripts directory

Tags: maven, flyway

How can I change the following `flyway-maven-plugin` configuration so that I can drop my scripts in `src/main/database` instead of `src/main/resources/db/migration`?

The [`migrate` mojo source code](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/793dd76b6c21c03c96a4dd4da30edd8e0114b6a5/flyway-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/maven/AbstractFlywayMojo.java#L166) seems to indicate that the default value is `db/migration`, but what about the `src/main/resources/`?

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:file:target/tmp</url>
                    <user>sa</user>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.190</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `locations` property to the directory you want. Prefix with `filesystem:` if it lives on the filesystem instead of the classpath: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/migrate.html

For your use case, use the following:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:file:target/tmp</url>
                    <user>sa</user>
                    <locations>
                        <location>filesystem:src/main/database</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.190</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Looks like I totally overviewed that, before deciding to go in the source code. Thanks!