# Unable to resolve location flyway

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, flyway

I'm trying to create an app using the microservices architecture. So now I'm creating the user service, but I faced with a small problem. I use flyway for database migrations and it doesn't work.

So, I have the big **global project** that looks like this:

[image]

And I also have **user service project** inside of this **global project**

[image]

In the **user_service** project I installed some maven dependencies and configured the plugin for flyway migrations.

Heres **user_service** **pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>user_service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <flyway.user>postgres</flyway.user>
        <flyway.password>4122</flyway.password>
        <flyway.schemas>working_schema</flyway.schemas>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postogramm_users</url>
                    <user>postgres</user>
                    <password>4122</password>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>working_schema</schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.24.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But when I try to migrate my database by this command:

`mvn flyway:migrate`
It says me that

```
Unable to resolve location filesystem:A:/java/projects/postogramm/src/main/java/org/postogramm/service/user_service/src/main/resource
s/db/migration
```

So what can be the problem? If you know, please tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Full log of flyway migration:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: windows
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.version: 10.0
[INFO] os.detected.version.major: 10
[INFO] os.detected.version.minor: 0
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: windows-x86_64
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< org.example:user_service >----------------------
[INFO] Building user_service 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:pom:6.1.6.Final has been relocated to org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:pom:6.1.6.Final
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3:migrate (default-cli) @ user_service ---
[INFO] Flyway 4.0.3 by Boxfuse
[INFO] Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postogramm_users (PostgreSQL 14.4)
[WARNING] Unable to resolve location filesystem:A:/java/projects/postogramm/src/main/java/org/postogramm/service/user_service/src/main/resource
s/db/migration
[WARNING] Unable to resolve location filesystem:A:/java/projects/postogramm/src/main/java/org/postogramm/service/user_service/src/main/resource
s/db/migration
[WARNING] Unable to resolve location filesystem:A:/java/projects/postogramm/src/main/java/org/postogramm/service/user_service/src/main/resource
s/db/migration
[INFO] Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.010s)
[INFO] Current version of schema "working_schema": << Empty Schema >>
[INFO] Schema "working_schema" is up to date. No migration necessary.
[WARNING] Unable to resolve location filesystem:A:/java/projects/postogramm/src/main/java/org/postogramm/service/user_service/src/main/resource
s/db/migration
[WARNING] Unable to resolve location filesystem:A:/java/projects/postogramm/src/main/java/org/postogramm/service/user_service/src/main/resource
s/db/migration
[WARNING] Unable to resolve location filesystem:A:/java/projects/postogramm/src/main/java/org/postogramm/service/user_service/src/main/resource
s/db/migration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.806 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-12T15:03:46+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is the path actually correct? You could try to define the path explicitly [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373688/change-flyway-maven-plugins-default-scripts-directory). [Correct docs link](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/maven-goal-migrate-184127434.html) and [possible parameters](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/parameters-184127474.html)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yeah, thank you very much! I just put the full data to resources directory and that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on the marked points I have done for your project structure

[image]

You can't have this structure since this is not a standard maven archetype.

I believe you need to remove the marked with green directories and leave out only the red representing the specific user_service java classes and resources.